# Compare cells of common rows in different files

Tags: vba, excel, loops

**What I have until now:**

The code below scans 2 sheets and checks if the same cells have identical values.If not , highlights the cell that has the discrepancy of the first sheet.

**What I need extra:**

I have to compare the common rows between two Files(nd not sheets),through a numbering in the first column of every file.

So, If the first cell(A column) of a row in the first file has the number "256" in it, the code has to find in the second file the row with the "256" number in its first cell(A column) and then compare the cells of the two rows for discrepancies.

If there is no such a row in the second file(meaning if there is not the number 256 in any of the cells of the first column) , the code creates in a cell an entry with an error message.

[Here is an image that explains, with an example, what I need as an extra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onA28.jpg) .

Below is the code where I am stuck:

**EDIT: 
I found and post a piece of code that checks the first column of both sheets for missing values. It works perfect but I cannot build the conditional "if" that compares if the similar cells of the two rows(of the two sheets), have discrepancies.Can anyone help?**

```
Option Explicit

Sub HighlightMatches()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Declare variables
    Dim var As Variant, iSheet As Integer, iRow As Long, iRowL As Long, bln As Boolean

       'Set up the count as the number of filled rows in the first column of Sheet1.
       iRowL = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

       'Cycle through all the cells in that column:
       For iRow = 1 To iRowL
          'For every cell that is not empty, search through the first column in each worksheet in the
          'workbook for a value that matches that cell value.

          If Not IsEmpty(Cells(iRow, 1)) Then
             For iSheet = ActiveSheet.Index + 1 To Worksheets.Count
                bln = False
                var = Application.Match(Cells(iRow, 1).Value, Worksheets(iSheet).Columns(1), 0)

                'If you find a matching value, indicate success by setting bln to true and exit the loop;
                'otherwise, continue searching until you reach the end of the workbook.
                If Not IsError(var) Then
                   bln = True
                   Exit For
                End If
             Next iSheet
          End If

          'If you do not find a matching value, do not bold the value in the original list;
          'if you do find a value, bold it.
          If bln = False Then

             Else
             Cells(iRow, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 9

             'here should be the conditional if

          End If
       Next iRow
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Not answering your q but to speed things up a bit, I would use worksheetfunction.countif then worksheetfunction.match to look for the row with the value in (instead of looping within a loop)

Comment: @jamheadart  thanks a lot for the info!!!!

Comment: @jamheadart could it be better if instead of worksheetfunction.match use the worksheetfunction.lookup? I mean , I don't care for the position of the entry, I need to match the entries in the two sheets so I can compare the rest of the cells in the two matching rows.